# What caused the tendency for conservatives to not support climate change regulations?

Tags: united-states, conservatism, climate-change

In the United States, conservatives tend to be against climate change regulations more frequently than the rest of the population.

Conservatives in the U.S. tend to hold traditional and Christian values. However, none of these values are directly incompatible with climate change reform, nor with the idea of climate change itself. Moreover, I do not know of any Christian theologies or denominations that are incompatible with it. So, what caused this tendency to emerge in U.S. politics?

Comment: You make a couple of leaps here that are hard to follow. First, you describe it as "conservatives" and "the rest of the population". But conservatives are a pretty large chunk of the population of the US, not some fringe group. Second, you describe conservatives as holding Christian values, but its unclear why that would be the only motivating factor for them. Christianity for example doesn't really say anything about foreign trade policy, yet conservatives have opinions on that.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg (1) I never said they were a fringe group. "The rest of the population" just means the part of the population that isn't conservative. (2) For some reason I thought that climate change and Christianity were related for some reason (I never thought hard about it). That's why I brought it up.

Comment: You are focusing on social conservatives and their largely Christian identity, but there are fiscal conservatives, like the group [republicEn](https://www.republicen.org), that support climate change reform through free-market solutions.

Comment: Comments deleted. This is not the place to discuss climate change.

Answer (score 83):

### Big business

Politics (of either mainstream party) in the USA is dependent on money from big business.  Many of those big businesses prioritise short term profit over long term environmental preservation, or have bonus systems that promote short term (<5 years) gains over long term (>100 years) gains.  Climate change action may reduce short term profits, in particular for businesses heavily invested in fossil fuels.  Companies working in the oil and gas industry
[donate more to Republicans than to Democrats](https://howmuch.net/articles/the-30-biggest-political-donors-on-the-fortune-500) (see Western Refining and ExxonMobil in particular), and presently, the Republican Party is the primary home of conservatives in the USA.  On the other hand, there is also a lot of money to be made in climate change action, and many high tech companies donate a lot more to the Democrats than to the Republicans, so one can equally argue that Democrat politicians support climate change action not out of idealism but due to corporate donations (I'm not saying this argument is right or wrong, but it can be made).

### Populism

Climate change action may be (correctly or not) perceived to affect the short term lifestyle of consumers.  Propaganda by big business may stress those aspects of climate change action that have such an impact.  Some voters may dislike the idea of a impact on their short term lifestyle, and thus be happy to listen.

Of course, for some people, such as employees in the fossil fuel industry (coal miners), the short term impact on their life may be major, in particular if they do not successfully transition into new industries (with or without government help).

### "Small government" conservatism

Many proposals for the mitigation of climate change require government action including taxation, and many conservatives are inherently skeptical of any government intervention in the economy in general and of taxation in particular.  A tax on CO₂ emissions is a government intervention and a taxation, and even many conservatives who support climate change action in principle may oppose such a taxation because they want to reduce taxation in general, preferring "market based" solutions such as CO₂ trading schemes (although the latter is still a government intervention; I don't know what such a market based solution would look like without any government-organised pricing of externalities in some way)¹.

### Denial

In the USA (and, perhaps to a lesser degree, in Europe), there still exist mainstream politicians who either deny the science of anthropogenic climate change altogether, or state that the impacts are exaggerated.  For the groups mentioned above (at least the first two bullet points), it may be convenient to deny that the problem exists, so that they don't need to answer why they won't support action to resolve the problem.  See [Fizz' answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/41786/130) for evidence on the partisan divide in accepting scientific findings on climate change.  There may be a handful of people who state that God created the Earth and therefore humans cannot change the climate, but that view is probably not held by a large number of people (see also [Rogers answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/41769/130)).

Even among those who accept anthropogenic climate change, some may argue that action is useless because other/bigger countries aren't taking action, but I don't know if this view is more prevalent among conservatives than among progressives.

---

¹<sup>I suppose that a libertarian-legalistic answer would be that the inhabitants of Bangladesh in 200 years can simply sue all the world's industry emitting CO₂ between 1850 and 2050 for drowning them, or something like that.  You may be able to tell I don't really buy this approach to environmental pollution including climate change.  If one takes the "don't cause harm to others" principle to the extreme, that would imply radical environmentalism, as any air pollution or greenhouse gas emissions contributes to harming others at present and in the future.</sup>

Comment: Under populism you don't seem to include the loss of jobs for certain geographic areas.  While those job losses may be offset elsewhere certain geographic areas are net losers in terms of jobs, which makes the population there into upset populist voters.

Comment: @MarkRogers You are right that I did not address that point, but why would that lead to *conservatives* not support climate change action?  It might as well lead to progressives not support such.

Comment: @gerrit - Well conservatives do care about how rural communities are doing, which is one of their centers of power.   The job loss gives them an argument to use against climate change in favor of big business and libertarianism.    Their argument is often that regulation leads to job loss and they can hold this up as an example.  While one would think that fighting job loss is progressive, it can be used to fuel conservative talking points.  Unemployment can be seen as a criticism of capitalism, if there is less unemployment then capitalism maybe perceived as doing well.

Comment: You missed one reason. There are also those who believe that pollution is primarily the fault of China and India, and any changes in the US would have little to no effect on the climate overall. The solution then would be to wait until the standard of living in those countries increases enough that climate becomes a concern to the native population.

Comment: @Strill Is that view more prevalent among conservatives than among progressives, though?

Comment: Re *"I'm not saying this argument is right or wrong, but it can be made"*:  random arguments that *"can be made"*, without citations or few eminent proponents specifically named, implies the possibility of a waffling endorsement.

Comment: @Strill "wait until the standard of living increases" — climate change affects the poor worse than the rich, but the rich contribute much more to the causes, so that reasoning is rather backwards.  I'm not sure how people who think that way are reasoning.  And China does act, of course.

Answer (score 54):

- Proposed solutions to climate change are (almost?) all based on handing greater power to the government, and Conservatives are traditionally for smaller government.
- Proposed solutions to climate change come at a cost of increased taxation or economic slowdown, and Conservatives are traditionally in favor of free market and lower taxes.
- Big business donors lobby against policies that could hurt them.
- They may believe that climate change has been co-opted by Liberals, who are using it to promote their own political agenda, and so it is natural for Conservatives to oppose what the other side is proposing (and vice-versa).
- Most importantly, they do not believe in (man-made) climate change, or at least do not believe that solutions proposed are effective and/or reasonable or practical. There have been numerous failed climate change predictions, the temperature data is wrapped up in complicated models, and in the age of fake news, it is easy to disbelieve the establishment narrative, especially when it is used by your political opponents.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94305/discussion-on-answer-by-blini-what-caused-the-tendency-for-conservatives-to-not).

Answer (score 42):

To give a somewhat [glib answer](https://www.vox.com/energy-and-environment/2019/4/26/18512213/climate-change-republicans-conservatives), Fox News.

In a 2019 poll, 12% of Republicans who watch Fox News believe in man-made climate change; the percentage among Republicans who don't watch Fox News rises to 28%.

[image]

Of course, this doesn't explain the profile of Fox News viewers in any further detail.

There's an older [academic study (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1940161211425410) which looked at additional factors. They have two linear regression models, one without and one with some [interaction terms](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/307/) between choice of news channel and political-party orientation ("partisanship" as they called it.)
(The product terms use mean-centered variables.) Beta(s) in the table below are [standardized](http://www.demog.berkeley.edu/~andrew/teaching/standard_coeff.pdf) regression coefficients; the B's are the usual regression coefficients and SE is standard error for those.

[image]

There is a perhaps a slight influence of church attendance and/or biblical values but nowhere near as much the choice of media consumed. Good political-values predictors were belief in small government (labeled "individualism") and [rejection of] redistribution etc. (labelled "egalitarianism").

Here's the rundown of the factors in that table, as they were measured:

> - Age in years (M = 46.4, SD = 16.8)
> - Gender (48.1 percent male)
> - Race (69.3 percent white)
> - Education (Range = 1 [less than high school] to 5 [post-graduate degree];
>     Median = 3 [some college])
> - Income (Range = 1 [less $25,000] to 5 [$100,000 or more]; Median = 4
>     [$50,000-$74,999])
>
> Media Use
>
> - Days per week read a printed newspaper (M = 3.6, SD = 2.7)
> - Days per week read news online (M = 3.7, SD = 2.7)
> - Cable news use. Using a response scale from (1) “never” to (4) “often,” respondents
>     were asked to report how frequently they watch CNN (M = 2.2, SD = 1.1),
>     MSNBC (M = 2.0, SD = 1.0), and the Fox News cable channel (M = 2.2, SD = 1.1).7
>     Because the correlation between CNN and MSNBC was substantial (r = .66, p <
>     .001), responses to these two items were averaged to form a combined measure of
>     CNN/MSNBC cable viewing (M = 2.1, SD = 1.0). This was further justified given that
>     the content analysis results indicated similar trends in climate change coverage across these two networks.
> - Network TV news use (Range = 1 [never] to 5 [often]; Median = 3 [sometimes])
> - Global warming information-seeking (Mean of three items: “How much
>     attention do you pay to information about global warming?” “In the past
>     30 days, how much have you actively looked for information about global
>     warming?” and “How closely do you follow news about the environment?”
>     Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates higher information seeking; α = .80; M =
>     2.0, SD = 0.7).
>
> Values and Predispositions
>
> - Political partisanship. Respondents were asked to specify their party identification
>     (Democrat, Republican, Independent, other, or no affiliation). Those
>     who identified as Independent or Other were then asked to indicate whether
>     they see themselves as closer to the Republican Party, the Democratic Party, or
>     neither. A 5-point ordinal partisanship measure was constructed from these
>     responses (Democrat, lean Democrat, Independent/other/no affiliation, lean
>     Republican, Republican; M = 2.8, SD = 1.6).
> - Frequency of religious service attendance (Range = 1 [never] to 6 [more than
>     once a week]; Median = 3 [a few times a year])
> - Biblical values (Mean agreement with three items: “Human beings, as we
>     know them today, evolved from earlier species of animals” [reverse-coded];
>     “One must believe in God in order to be moral and have good values”; “Just
>     as the Bible says, the world literally was created in six days.” Range = 1 to 4,
>     where 4 indicates stronger biblical values; α = .77; M = 2.6, SD = 0.9)
> - Egalitarianism (Mean agreement with four items: “The world would be
>     a more peaceful place if its wealth were divided more equally among
>     nations”; “In my ideal society, all basic needs would be guaranteed by the
>     government for everyone”; “I support government programs to get rid of
>     poverty”; “Discrimination against minorities is still a very serious problem
>     in our society.” Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates more egalitarianism; α =
>     .72; M = 2.6, SD = 0.7)
> - Individualism (Mean agreement with five items: “If the government spent
>     less time trying to fix everyone’s problems, we’d all be a lot better off”; “Our
>     government tries to do too many things for too many people. We should just
>     let people take care of themselves”; “The government interferes too much in
>     our everyday lives”; “Government regulation of business usually does more
>     harm than good”; “People should be allowed to make as much money as
>     they can, even if it means some make millions while others live in poverty.”
>     Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates more individualistic attitudes; α = .77;
>     M = 2.6; SD =0.6)
> - Materialism (Mean agreement with four items: “You can tell if people are successful
>     by the things they own and the way they dress”; “It’s very important
>     to me to have a home as well-equipped and furnished as that of other people
>     I know”; “I follow the latest trends and fashions”; “I prefer brands and products
>     that make me feel accepted by others.” Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates
>     greater materialism; α = .67; M = 1.9; SD =0.6)
> - Approval of modern science (Agreement with statement “Overall, modern
>     science does more harm than good”; Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates more
>     disagreement; M = 3.1; SD = 0.8)
> - Environmentalism (Agreement with statement “I consider myself an environmentalist”;
>     Range = 1 to 4, where 4 indicates more agreement; M = 2.5;
>     SD = 0.8)

As for the dependent variable in that regression, they asked 5 questions about global warming, but the answers were so highly correlated that they combined in to a single index/response.

> Five beliefs and perceptions were used as indicators of global warming acceptance:
>   the perception of scientific agreement on global warming, belief in the human causes
>   of global warming, certainty that global warming is happening, concern about the
>   impact of global warming, and the valence of expectations regarding the outcomes
>   of taking action on global warming. For the sake of parsimony, these five variables
>   were combined into a single omnibus index, which served as the dependent variable
>   in our analyses. A principal components factor analysis confirmed that these five
>   variables load on a single factor (eigenvalue = 2.92; all factor loadings > .64), and
>   internal reliability was high (a = .82).

Details for each of these 5 questions omitted by me here.

[Research in other countries](https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:945529/FULLTEXT01.pdf) (Sweden, Brazil) also found that rejection of egalitarianism (as measured by more standardized [social dominance orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_dominance_orientation)
 questionnaires) is a good predictor of climate change denial. So the (positive) correlation with anti-egalitarianism is hardly a unique US phenomenon.

Comment: Correlation, causation, or both?

Comment: Wow, that first visualisation is the most unintuitively designed thing I've ever seen.

Comment: Perhaps a quick run down on what Model 1 and Model 2 is, as well as what B (SE) and Beta is would be useful.

Comment: @PyRulez: the only difference is that one model has an interaction term and the other doesn't. For some background see any textbook on statistics (linear regression) or on-line equivalent e.g. https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/307/

Comment: @Fizz okay, they are correlation coefficients. That's what I was wondering.

Comment: I think it's clear that Fox news is a powerful instrument in this case, but the question of *why* they're pushing this agenda isn't really answered and is the point of OP's question.  I think the key reasons in gerrit's answer provide some explanation as to *why* Fox news is invested in its particular viewpoints.  The strongest correlation in that study is information-seeking behaviour in news media consumption, which really tells us that some measure of intelligence is the largest divider.

Comment: @J...: perhaps, but it gets down to determining causation for Fox News' motivation/programming. Is it because of their audience, their ownership etc., a combination (if so how much should each factor account for)? Perhaps someone has looked into this, but insofar I haven't found more than opinions on what motivates Fox. At least one study found that over all media, ownership explained less than audience: https://web.stanford.edu/~gentzkow/research/biasmeas.pdf

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO but I think you should add a small paragraph or two to mention the [role that Conservative Philanthropists like John M. Olin](https://megaphone.link/VMP6945626900) played in shaping the political debate.

Answer (score 22):

To speak purely to the Christian theological point -- some theologians have interpreted **Genesis 9:11** to be relevant:

> And I will establish my covenant with you, neither shall all flesh be
>   cut off any more by the waters of a flood; neither shall there any
>   more be a flood to destroy the earth.

[U.S. Representative John Shimkus (Republican) made this argument in 2010](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/us-politics/8123790/Congressman-says-God-will-save-us-from-climate-change.html):

> "I believe that's the infallible word of God, and that's the way it's
>   going to be for his creation.  The Earth will end only when God
>   declares it's time to be over. Man will not destroy this Earth. This
>   Earth will not be destroyed by a Flood. I do believe that God's word
>   is infallible, unchanging, perfect."

Comment: Yes, this is a salient point, along with the Second Coming and various eschatological beliefs. Of course, contrarily, the first chapter of Genesis is the main Christian argument in favour of climate change reform, but it is definitely not as serious for Christians as it is for atheists. It is not about the survival of the planet - it is simply about obeying God's command to look after the planet.

Comment: I thought of this, but I decided not to add it to the answer, because I do not believe it to be a major cause of the dominant conservative thought on climate change.  To go back 9 years quoting a single representative may be considered [nutpicking](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Nutpicking).

Comment: That quote illustrates a popular misconception about climate change too. We won't (can't) "destroy this Earth". But we're perfectly capable of *changing* the landscape of the Earth such that many species of animals and billions of people are killed. Whether this is an issue for you depends very much on where you are, or what places you care about. If you live in Nauru, this is an existential threat. If you live in Wyoming, you may not even notice, and the loss of coral on the Great Barrier Reef might not be something you care about.

Comment: -1 Because you lump "Christians" together in one group and represent us with some Republican US Representative that I've never heard of. I'm Catholic, and there is [this one guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Francis) who speaks for a billion of us Christians, and he says to [be mindful of climate change](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/encyclicals/documents/papa-francesco_20150524_enciclica-laudato-si.html).

Comment: @kingledion I'm glad you aren't part of the majority of conservative Christians who don't believe in climatology, but the fact remains that _you aren't the majority_. White mainline and evangelical Protestants and white Catholics display the lowest levels of concern about climate change among all ethnic/religious groupings, with 60% of white Catholics saying they are somewhat or very unconcerned (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0096340215599789).

Comment: @kingledion This doesn't hold for Hispanic Catholics or black Protestants, but those groups generally aren't conservative Christians anyway (https://www.people-press.org/2018/03/20/1-trends-in-party-affiliation-among-demographic-groups/).

Answer (score 16):

It is impossible to answer this question for every Conservative; each may have their own reasons for the determination they've come to. So, the following answer is a representation of the reasoning, in the conservative circles I travel, that the prospect of anthroprogenic climate change is questionable, thus doubting the need for regulation. There are four main points, highlighted below with amplifying information. They will be followed by a summary.

## **Massive Opening Clarion Statement**

This answer is not about the truth of the following claims. Instead, it is an explainer for the "tendency of conservatives" to not support climate change regulations, because many of them don't are skeptical about claims on Anthroprogenic Global Warming. If they hold AGW in doubt, the cost-benefit curve of regulatory actions are less supported.

**[History of Data Manipulation](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2017/feb/5/climate-change-whistleblower-alleges-noaa-manipula/)**
There are two significant incidents where it has been revealed after the fact that those developing the AGW narrative have made demonstrated lapses in integrity. First was the Hockey Stick graph, first released in 1999 (Mann, Bradley, and Hughes). It was subsequently weighed down with challenges to the statistical methods it used and a critique questioning  the choice to minimize the statistical influence of the Medieval Warming Period, the latter highlighted by the differences in the IPCC reports between 1990 and 2001. The integrity of the work was further tainted by the hacking of climate research email servers which provided a perspective of conspiracy (more later). 
More recently, the choice of NOAA to 'adjust' recorded temperature information, lowering earlier records and raising current records, furthers the perspective of manipulation.

**[Data Not](http://thehill.com/policy/energy-environment/258375-agency-wont-give-gop-internal-docs-on-climate-research) Available for Review**
In addition to the question of data integrity, there is an ongoing complaint that many of the reports and news articles present the results of an review, without providing the source information and methodology for evaluation.

[**Active Conspiracies**](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/columnists/christopherbooker/6679082/Climate-change-this-is-the-worst-scientific-scandal-of-our-generation.html)
While some level of confidentiality and opaqueness is expected in scientific exploration, the lengths that the proponents for climate change goes to doesn't help the perception that something untoward is going on behind the scenes. This is worsened be previously referenced release of emails from within a climate change organization that reflected those concerns.

[**Abandonment of the Scientific Process**](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/04/23/rand-paul-climate-change_n_5200586.html)
The line that creates the most cringing response is "the science is settled," with the impression being that it has been proven that man made actions have an influence on climate change. As if all factors were understood, all the data was in, and that it was definitively proven that man has a measureable impact on the climate. In this case, the intention that the exhausts of man made technologies has an influence on climate change (again, more later), requires an in depth understanding of a multitude of factors, which non-exhaustively includes: solar cycles, irregularities of the planets orbit, irregularities of the planets rotation, the cyclical nature of prevailing winds, interaction of the moon on the tides and the resulting effects, irregularities of the planet's core hydraulic rotation, shifting of the continental shelves, variation of volcanic heating influences on the oceans, and many, many more. Further, the claim that carbon dioxide is a pollutant, which is held true in order to curtail it's production, is questionable. An increased availability of carbon dioxide would encourage an expanse in plant growth.

[**Summary**](https://thinkprogress.org/the-anti-science-climate-denier-caucus-732ec3a2a4d4#.uip4vt5i6)
Climate Change does exist; there are cyclical pattern that can be demonstrated in what weather does.

Comment: So, how does any of this answer why _conservatives, as opposed to progressives_ are critical about AGW? You're merely listing talking points which discredit the scientists; if these points are true (I won't discuss that here; as you may be able to guess I disagree but this is off-topic here) then it should be just as much reason for skepticism on the Left as on the Right.

Comment: "It far easier to prove the negative, that a thing doesn't exist, than to ever prove a thing does exist." - This is exactly the opposite of how proving things works. See "Proving a Negative" under "Burden of Proof": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)#Proving_a_negative

Comment: @leftaroundabout These are Reasons that Conservates profess for being skeptical. The question asks why Conservatives tend to be skeptical. This answer takes no role in reflecting on why there is a shortage of skepticism among progressive camps.

Comment: @JackArbiter You're right, I worded that poorly.

Comment: Pretty much all of your claims about nefarious actions were debunked when investigated.  -1 for proliferating misinformation. If I could give you another -1 for talking about "climate cycles" and referencing "weather" I would.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet The Truth of the claims aren't isn't in question; it is whether or not there are conservative circles that hold those positions and view points. Since there are, there is diminished confidence in any of the science put forth from the AGW activism crowd.

Comment: You don't frame them as claims, you state them as fact, so, yes, the factual nature of the claims is relevant. You don't state that they *believe* data was manipulated, you state that data ***was*** manipulated. If you care to change your wording, I'll reconsider my downvote.

Comment: The opening paragraph is an explainer that claims that follow are the reasonings prominenent in the conservative circles with which I interact.

Comment: @DrunkCynic the opening paragraph does not indicate the relative truth of the points which follow it, so updating the language in each point to indicate which have been debunked and which are legitimate issues would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I suppose I was kind of ambiguous. In the body I asked about conservatives in relation to non-conservatives, but didn't include the stipulation in the title. I didn't realize it would make a difference.

Comment: The summary conflates specific theoretical types of weather, in this case *global warming*, (AKA *climate change*), with weather in general.

Comment: @agc It doesn't conflate them. The claim (whether true or not) is that some of the patterns cited as supporting AGW could potentially be due to natural climate cycles rather than anthropogenic causes. There are several natural climate cycles which are known (with varying levels of understanding of their mechanics,) but, especially since accurate, precise, and global record-keeping only goes back a few decades, it's not unlikely that there are additional climate cycles not yet understood, especially those with longer periods.

Comment: @agc No it doesn't. Climate Change exists, impacts can possibly be observed in weather variances.

Comment: @Morgen The Truth or debunked nature of the points is irrelevant. It is sufficient that there are crowds within the Conservative super tent that believe them despite any claims that the argument has been debunked. Since there are still skeptics that hold these points, the points matter as is.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, offering bad evidence without explaining belief. "Eight committees investigated the allegations and published reports, finding no evidence of fraud or scientific misconduct." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climatic_Research_Unit_email_controversy And "the science is settled," is a strawman no one believes, which directly contradicts the part of paragraph one complaining that models are updated (to account for previously unknown errors). And the linked article re:Bates, the old NOAA data was adjusted upward: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/348/6242/1469

Comment: My problem with this answer is that even if one conceded every single point it made, it would still be the wrong way to view the situation. There's an asymmetry in outcomes: if we fight AGW and it turns out to be a fabrication then we have a sub-optimal economy. Some people will probably die. If we *don't* fight it and it's real then **we all die**.

Comment: @JaredSmith How is your problem pertinent to the reasons that are held by Conservatives? It isn't about the points being made, but that there are conservative circles that make them.

Comment: I have a feeling most of these allegations, as stated, have been referenced and debunked on this very site via skeptics. It would add to the answer to link to those so there is context given. As stated, it does give the impression of these allegations as fact, even though the factual nature isn't directly in question, it is an important as a corollary. If an allegation is true, it has much more weight in answering the main question than a bunch of statements that are incorrectly believed.

Comment: @JaredSmith, you're venturing into subjective territory, which one should generally avoid in such a discussion. While it may seem logical to you, it may not be logical to someone else. The asymmetry you're talking about is entirely meaningless if your subjective view is entirely that the idea of AGW is incorrect. In such a case, there is no flip side of the coin, it is only a sub-optimal economy with no upside.

Comment: This claim that, over decades, using objective & rigorous methods, determining what the facts are presents a conflict of interest, when the "other side" of the debate has billions they are willing to pour into getting a friendly result, and they have a track record of doing so, makes that last comment pretty much baseless and snide conspiracy nonsense. The research that has led us to the current consensus has met the standards of science. It is telling that not one scientific study has refuted it. Those that specifically set out to do so have switched their stances, once the data was in.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers mention taxation, government expansion, etc. Those are good points, and definitely a big part of why conservatives generally don't support fighting AGW. But there's a pervasive reason that hasn't been mentioned:

> Because liberals support it, loudly and conspicuously.

To endorse the idea of man-made climate change in a conservative space is to invite accusations of being a RINO, a turncoat, someone who has lost the One True Way. Liberals further drive this dynamic by insulting loudly and at great length those who deny the facts as we understand them. Since mocking people tends to be a rather poor way to change their minds, conservatives entrench even further.

And this is a problem, because it's arguably the largest existential threat to humankind today.

Comment: This answer could be summarized in one word: "*spite*".  Please elaborate on whether or not this is a peculiarity of one party, both parties; or a side effect of certain systems within or of government; or the unfortunate expression some universal human trait; or something else...

Comment: @agc your one-word summary is priceless. And yes, this is a [universal truth of politics](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/9weLK2AJ9JEt2Tt8f/politics-is-the-mind-killer), a part of the human condition. It's not the only part of the answer to the OP's question, and it may not even be the most important part, but it's the part that was noticeably absent from the other answers at the time I wrote this.

Comment: Many liberal "green" movements are accused of doing it purely as a form virtue signaling, that they don't really care about the environment and don't invest any more resources in saving the climate than anyone else, they just claim to be green because it looks good, and they can use it to vilify their opponents. Far be it from me to dictate whether these accusations are true or not, but they are talked about, so it's not unreasonable for some conservatives to view supportive speeches for climate change regulations as a from of empty virtue signaling.

Comment: @vsz the problem is that reality doesn't care whether the motivations of the players (on either side) are pure, empty, or some mix of the two. The temperature of the planet and the consequences are brute facts. Which is why I'm particularly bitter that something so potentially important gets hijacked as a signaling mechanism.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better without the last mini-paragraph.  Up until then, it was a reasonable answer that a lot of people would agree with.  The paragraph above it talks about how mocking people is a terrible way of changing peoples' minds... followed by the final few sentences mocking people that don't agree with you.

Comment: @Kevin good catch, I deleted the last sentence. See how insidious it is? lol

Answer (score 12):

I think you're missing something fundamental to the Conservative parts of the Republican Party: government control. Let's break down climate change for a second and we can better spot the disagreements as we go

## The earth has gotten warmer since we started keeping records

[Scientific fact](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/world-of-change/DecadalTemp). Not many argue against this because the records go back long before the theories we have today.

## The earth got warmer due to carbon dioxide in the air

There are some minor disagreements here and there but [there seems to be a strong correlation](https://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/carbon-dioxide/). Still not that many political arguments at this level.

## Humans are the primary source of carbon dioxide

There's a case to be made here that humans are making it worse, but [carbon dioxide sources are somewhat varied](http://www.ces.fau.edu/nasa/module-4/causes/sources-carbon-dioxide.php). There's [some who disagree with this assessment](https://skepticalscience.com/human-co2-smaller-than-natural-emissions.htm) (not endorsing it either way, just noting it's there), and it's hard to solidify on either side because we don't have an easy way to determine all sources.

## Human activity is the root cause of climate change

This is where the friction gets going. The problem with this is that there are lots and lots of political alarmists in this arena like Al Gore, who produced the documentary [An Inconvenient Truth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0497116/), which has [proven to be inaccurate](https://dailycaller.com/2016/05/03/an-inconvenient-review-after-10-years-al-gores-film-is-still-alarmingly-inaccurate/)

> Gore also famously predicted storms would become more frequent and intense as man-made emissions warmed the oceans.
>
> “And of course when the oceans get warmer, that causes stronger storms,” Gore said in his film. “That same year that we had that string of big hurricanes, we also set an all-time record for tornadoes.”

Unfortunately, science has not backed that up

> The IPCC found in 2013 there “is limited evidence of changes in extremes associated with other climate variables since the mid-20th century.” The IPCC also found “no significant observed trends in global tropical cyclone frequency over the past century” and “[n]o robust trends in annual numbers of tropical storms, hurricanes and major hurricanes counts have been identified over the past 100 years in the North Atlantic basin.”

A similar problem was [criticism of George W. Bush in 2005 about Hurricane Katrina](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/09/02/health/bush-takes-heat-on-global-warming.html)

> "The Bush government rejects international climate protection goals by insisting that imposing them would negatively impact the American economy," wrote Jürgen Tritten, Germany's environment minister and a Green Party member.
>
> "The American president is closing his eyes to the economic and human costs his land and the world economy are suffering under natural catastrophes like Katrina," Tritten charged.

The problem there was that Katrina wasn't caused, or even made worse by, the policies of Bush

> But the experts add that it is scientifically unfair to blame any one hurricane on the warming trend.
>
> "We would expect hurricanes on average should be getting more intense because of global warming, but it's hard to make the connection in any one event, like Katrina," said Jay Gulledge, senior research fellow at the Pew Institute for Climate Change.

Let's put aside the science for a moment. Imagine one political side starts making wild claims that don't always match up to reality. Would the other side be more or less inclined to listen to them, even if there were more solid scientific arguments to be made?

## The solution to climate change is government regulation. Like RIGHT NOW

Here's [climate activist Greta Thunberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-05-24/swedish-teen-climate-activist-rips-politicians-ahead-of-eu-vote)

> One way forward would be to declare a global climate emergency, a proposal that she says has been backed by the U.K., Ireland and other countries, but not yet by Sweden.
>
> This would “send a clear signal that we’re in a crisis,” she said.

And an indirect rebuttal by [Conservative columnist Jonah Goldberg](https://www.nationalreview.com/g-file/unchecked-nationalism-dangers-pitfalls-statism/) (emphasis mine)

> In times of emergency, we’re all in it together. And that’s a good thing.
>
> But there are two caveats. The first is that emergencies do not last, and when the emergency is over, the old rules need to come back. If they don’t, then capitalism, democracy, and liberty are done for. Emergencies must be the exception to the rule, because if we make the spirit of emergency the rule, then we no longer live under the rule of law, but the rule of tyrants or mobs.
>
> **The second problem is that real emergencies must be obvious to all — or at least nearly all.** There are moral equivalents to war. A girl down a mine shaft is one. A meteor heading to earth is another, as are various forms of natural disasters, zombie, vampire, and C.H.U.D apocalypses, etc.
>
> The problem is that there are people who are very attracted to the power that comes with emergencies. Power is seductive in whatever form it takes: Emergency powers, money, Infinity Stones, the One Ring, or, as we’ve seen in the case of Jussie Smollet, the cultural power that comes with being able to claim you are a victim.
>
> **This leads people to declare emergencies when they do not exist or to exaggerate real challenges so they can do an end run around the conventional rules of democracy. There’s been a lot of the latter over the last decade or so.**

Now, not all of this is centered around emergency powers. The Democrat's [Green New Deal](https://www.cnn.com/2019/02/14/politics/green-new-deal-proposal-breakdown/index.html) isn't an emergency power grab, yet it can't resist being *political* either. Somehow it manages to link dealing with climate change to high speed rail (a long time Democrat favorite), labor law reforms, jobs and leave policy, free college, [no nuclear power](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/why-does-the-green-new-deal-push-for-green-energy-but-not-for-nuclear-energy), etc. In other words, give Democrats full control of the US economy and they'll solve all the problems of the world, along with climate change.

As such, it's unsurprising that Republicans have been more skeptical of the claims pushed by Democrats. Viewed through a political lens, it looks less like science and more like rhetoric to them.

Comment: Really? You're using a **Daily Caller** article as your source for a claim that _An Inconvenient Truth_ was proven wrong? Here's Media Bias/Fact Check's report on them: "Overall, we rate the Daily Caller strongly right biased based on story selection that almost always favors the right and Mixed for factual reporting due to numerous failed fact checks. The Daily Caller is a source that needs to be fact checked on a per article basis." https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/daily-caller/

Comment: @probably_someone Look, it doesn't matter which site I use at this point (and that Skeptical Science link is an easier target in that regard). 1. People will attack the sources they don't agree with. I could use a slightly more center source and still get the same response 2. The questions was why Conservative Republicans feel this way. It's hard not to quote from those sources in explaining that position. 3. That particular article has a lot of objective fact. They quote from external sources like the IPCC report. Gore got it wrong. The source doesn't change that.

Comment: @Machavity 1. The fact that people will attack an article no matter how misleading it is doesn't mean that you shouldn't care whether you post misleading things. It sounds like you want a justification to not care about the quality of your sources. Though this isn't the forum for it, I can explain exactly how the article you posted is misleading if you want. Also, given the choice among many sources addressing the documentary, the fact that you willingly chose this one speaks volumes.

Comment: @Machavity 2. You didn't say, "**Conservatives believe that** An Inconvenient Truth has been disproven." You said, "An Inconvenient Truth has been disproven." There's a big difference between those two. 3. The quote from the IPCC doesn't contradict the Gore quote. In the quote, Gore says that storms would be _stronger_, not that there would be _more_ of them. The IPCC quote says that there aren't more storms. That quote does _not_ say that storms aren't _stronger_, so it doesn't contradict Gore's quote. It's precisely this kind of bait-and-switch that makes this article misleading.

Comment: Also, regarding whether Gore "got it wrong" - here's a review from climate scientists around that time.... http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2006/05/al-gores-movie/
   There was also a lawuit to prevent it from being shown in schools shortly after that time, where the expert testimony was that the science was "broadly accurate" -  https://skepticalscience.com/print.php?r=187  More recent retrospectives echo this, as well - https://www.sciencenews.org/article/changing-climate-10-years-after-inconvenient-truth

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear to me why religion is given as a factor, see [Conservatism in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism_in_the_United_States#Types).

> Conservatism in the United States is not a single school of thought.

I, for example, am a Constitutional conservative, not a Christian conservative.

Also, see [Opposition to environmentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism_in_the_United_States#Opposition_to_environmentalism).

> Conservative think tanks since the 1990s have opposed the concept of man-made global warming; they challenged scientific evidence, publicised what they perceived as beneficial aspects of global warming, and stated their strong beliefs that proposed remedies would do more harm than good. The concept of anthropogenic global warming continues to be an ongoing debate among Conservatives in the United States, but the majority reject the scientific consensus that climate change is caused by humans; 73% of Republicans believed humans were uninvolved in causing global warming, according to a 2015 poll by Pew Research.
>
> In recent times, American conservatives have generally supported deregulation of pollution and reduced restrictions on carbon emissions. Similarly, they have advocated increased oil drilling with less regulatory interference, such as in the Arctic National Wildlife Refuge. In the 2008 election, the phrase, "Drill baby drill" was used to express the Republican position on the subject.

---

Preponderance of research is less than preponderance of evidence due to  [Falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability#Overview).

> The classical view of the philosophy of science is that it is the goal of science to prove hypotheses like "All swans are white" or to induce them from observational data. The Inductivist methodology supposes that one can somehow move from a series of statements such as 'here is a white swan', 'over there is a white swan', and so on, to a universal statement such as 'all swans are white'. As observed by David Hume, Immanuel Kant and later by Popper and others, this method is clearly deductively invalid, since it is always possible that there may be a non-white swan that has eluded observation (and, in fact, the discovery of the Australian black swan demonstrated the deductive invalidity of this particular statement). This is known as the problem of induction.

<del>There is a lack of deductive evidence for anthropogenic global warming; this means there is room for skepticism.</del>

[To clear up some apparent confusion, since *lack of* does not always mean *no*.]

There is not enough deductive evidence to reach a definitive conclusion for  anthropogenic global warming; this means there is room for skepticism. While some level of [Scientific skepticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeptical_movement#Scientific_skepticism) is normal, the level of skepticism of conservatives in the Climate Science claim of AGW is quite high.

---

From Pew Research Center, [How Americans see climate change in 5 charts](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/04/19/how-americans-see-climate-change-in-5-charts/):

> 5 Partisanship is a stronger factor in people’s beliefs about climate change than is their level of knowledge and understanding about science.

[image: Pew Research Center Chart]

> In 2016, 93% of Democrats (including leaners) with a high level of knowledge about science said climate change is mostly due to human activity, compared with 49% of Democrats with low science knowledge, based on a nine-item index. By contrast, Republicans and GOP-leaning independents with a high level of science knowledge were no more likely than those with a low level of knowledge to say climate change is mostly due to human activity.

Among those with a high level of science knowledge, the difference between 23% and 93% shows a very high degree of skepticism. Conservatives don't trust the data and don't trust those providing the data.

From Pew Research Center, [Conservative Republicans especially skeptical of climate scientists’ research and understanding](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/10/04/conservative-republicans-especially-skeptical-of-climate-scientists-research-and-understanding/):

[image: Pew Research Center Chart]

> Many conservative Republicans have a negative view of scientists’ understanding of climate change.
>
> Conservative Republicans are closely divided over whether to trust information from climate scientists:
>
> Many conservative Republicans express doubts about whether the work of climate scientists is based on the best available evidence.
>
> Conservative Republicans are more doubtful than others about motives behind climate research findings.

---

As requested in a comment *You should explain what the second half of this post is supposed to have to do with the question.*:

The title question: *What caused the tendency for conservatives to not support climate change reform?* I'm a conservative. *Conservative think tanks since the 1990s have opposed the concept of man-made global warming; they challenged scientific evidence ...*. I'm  skeptical of the scientific evidence. Those who are skeptics need not necessarily explain why; it amounts to trying to prove a negative. I provided an explanation.

Comment: To be clear, you would dismiss any scientific research because its not based on mathematical logic? That's essentially what your statement about inductive versus deductive logic reduces to.

Comment: You should explain what the second half of this post is supposed to have to do with the question. Are conservatives necessarily more in a deductive mindset whereas progressives think inductively? (For the argument itself: I daresay it's pretty stupid. By much the same reasoning you could argue that all national defense can be scrapped because there is no deductive evidence that your country will ever be attacked in the future. And anyways there _is_ evidence for AGW; relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ6Z04VJDco)

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Basically, yes. It is not necessary for me to understand all of the details of the research, only that experiments were done and an explanation is available to support the conclusion. I need more than to blindly accept anything that appears similar to [Spontaneous generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_generation).

Comment: @leftaroundabout - The deductive evidence, such as it is, for national defense is found in the recurring conflicts that exist around the world. And, no, I'm not going to watch the video.

Comment: By your definition there is a lack of deductive evidence for the theory of gravity, yet conservatives pretty broadly seem to accept that. I posit that there's something else going on here.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson - No one is trying to convince others and government to regulate gravity; thus no political conflict about which one should be skeptical. The rest involves scientific skepticism, the scientific method, Karl Popper, and my own research (over a period of more than 19 years) into other matters that are not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @RickSmith there are pretty rigorous regulations regarding the statics of buildings, which only make sense under the premise that gravity will still work as before when building actually stands. Most conservatives don't seem to find this inappropriate, despite the inductive reasoning involved.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Yes buildings, bridges, and torpedoes all rely on gravity. Gravity is measurable, even if it is not yet understood how it works. And the sun will come up tomorrow ... I mean ... the earth will rotate to give the appearance ... oh, never mind. But, the question is, will AWG stop and reverse on its own, will new evidence arise to show other significant factors are involved, etc.? If several trillion dollars are spent on mitigation, who will reimburse those costs if someone says, Oops!

Comment: False: *There is a lack of deductive evidence for anthropogenic global warming*.  There is in fact [overwhelming deductive evidence](https://www.ipcc.ch/report/ar5/syr/).

Comment: @RickSmith [*what if it's all a big hoax and we create a better world for nothing?*](http://greenwei.com/blog/what-if-its-a-hoax-and-we-create-a-better-world-for-nothing/)

Comment: Resorting to Karl Popper and sophisticated logical sophistry to undermine the obvious fact of Anthropogenic Climate Change is the last desperate act of the Denialist. But in any case, as others have pointed out, there is overwhelming deductive evidence that humans burning carbon fuels has increased CO2, which has absorbed solar IR, which has forced atmospheric temperature to increase, which is altering the climate.

Comment: "There is not enough deductive evidence to reach a definitive conclusion for anthropogenic global warming" There has never been a definitive conclusion in science about anything, ever. Why is this one specific case the one that requires unachievable standards of quality, while others don't? GPS works. The internet works. These things work IN SPITE OF the fact that no absolute conclusions have ever been drawn about the principles which make them possible (quantum mechanics, the speed of light, etc.)

Comment: Ok, so this answer applies to _you_, but it's not clear that it applies to conservatives _in general_. In fact, I would argue that you're among a small minority of conservatives in the US: according to Gallup, 50% of conservatives say they look to religion most for guidance on what is right and wrong (https://www.pewforum.org/religious-landscape-study/political-ideology/conservative/), compared with only 18% of liberals and 26% of moderates. Even if you personally don't think religion factors into it, more than half of conservatives think it does (since 50% said they look to it the most).

Comment: @probably_someone - The title question is _What caused the tendency for conservatives to not support climate change regulations?_ My answer is skepticism and lack of trust. That would include the 45% who say the Word of God should be taken literally, since that belief could engender skepticism and lack of trust with regard to the need for climate change regulation. My lack of religiosity is unimportant in that regard. I simply do not emphasize religion as being necessary to understand the _tendency_.

Comment: "There is not enough deductive evidence to reach a definitive conclusion for anthropogenic global warming" You're right, I guess we just can't know who to believe.  [NASA](https://climate.nasa.gov/scientific-consensus/), or [Exxon](http://america.aljazeera.com/articles/2015/7/9/exxon-knew-of-human-role-in-climate-change-in-1981.html)?  There's just no way we could possibly discern evidence, factoring in ideological or financial conflict of interest, or gauge educated consensus.  There's just too much ambiguity when 97% of climate scientists and most US scientific organisations say one thing.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually several opposing aspects to this issue for US republicans.

- Republicans are nominally pro-small government and deregulation. In reality, modern republican politicians are somewhat hypocritical, where they will appear to be pro-small government but actually support massive expansion of certain public activity such as defense and induce crony capitalism through the MIC as well as other industries (eg. fracking). However, for many other sectors they are still pro-small government, pro-private enterprise, pro-freedom for companies to do as they want and anti-regulation. Environmental matters fall in this latter group.
- Supporters of climate change regulation (CCR) are usually educated progressive elites. Some of the opposition is basically motivated by "always do the opposite of what liberals say".
- Besides simple ideological opposition, conservatives also do not trust academics in general, because they perceive that academics subvert or misrepresent science in order to push their own progressive agendas. Thus the claim that climate change occurs or can/should be prevented is not credible to begin with for conservatives. Republican politicians will avoid directly contradicting it in public, because the media would crucify them. But they try to avoid the subject and speak in dog whistle to still covertly imply to their base that they don't believe climate change is real - without actually saying so.
- The republican base is opposed to CCR, whether rationally or irrationally, therefore the republican politicians and talking-heads are also opposed, so it's a self-amplifying cycle.
- CCRs often pass on the burden to consumers, who end up not only footing the bill for cleaning up all the public resources the corporations got to exploit for free, but also pay extra because the corporations inject profit margins in the various "green" undertakings. Consumers are already burdened by inflation, growing cost of living and lackluster wages (for low-income people) that they feel additional inflation induced by CCRs prices them out of many essential goods, like cars.
- Environmentalism in general has become unpopular with conservatives due to various progressive pro-environment movements, such as veganism. These have been driven by progressives, and also have been framed in terms of conservative values, so they have historically failed to appeal to conservatives and as a result conservatives are generally suspicious of any environmentalist cause supported by liberals.
- A lot of CCRs emerge from urban areas, major universities and large governmental bureaucracies. Rural conservatives feel that these solutions are out of touch, possibly suitable for their urban area but divorced from the realities of their rural life. Liberals sometimes add fuel to the fire by acting like conservatives should just accept their livelihood being destroyed "for the common good".
- Many large companies stand to profit more in absence of CCRs for obvious reasons, therefore they lobby politicians (and covertly proselytize to the public) to that effect.
- A lot of environmental damage is actually caused by other countries, such as China and India, which impose far fewer regulations and expenses on their citizens, compared to the US. For conservatives, it is unfair that America should go above and beyond when these countries are not pulling their weight. They see it as something that will weaken America's economic and strategic advantage, and oppose it out of patriotism.

However, despite all of this, it is not entirely true that conservatives oppose CCRs, disbelieve climate change and hate the environment. For example, in conservative, rural states, preserving natural resources is a very popular conservative issue that doesn't make it to national news. A lot of this has to do with preserving hunting and fishing, but usually the public in these areas is interested in keeping these activities sustainable. Historically, there have been cases of conservative pro-environment initiatives in other countries as well. However, climate change (for those conservatives that accept it as real and relevant) has been too poisoned by progressive involvement, if you will, for conservatives to not opposed it in reaction in today's very partisan society.

Answer (score 0):

The Republican National Committee has a pro-fossil fuel stance.  Now, we might ascribe various true motivations behind this that others detail very well, but it also helps to see what they argue as well.

In [their 2016 platform document](https://prod-cdn-static.gop.com/static/home/data/platform.pdf) the Republican Party sets forth such arguments as

- hindering fossil fuel based energy would hurt struggling families
- America has huge reserves of fossil fuels and using our own resources would free the US from dependence on foreign oil or energy that requires rare-earth metals supplied mainly from China
- exporting our fossil fuels will generate a lot of wealth for America

Comment: Sounds like the GOP has a pro family and pro US stance, not the other way around.

Answer (score -2):

"conservative" ... "reform".  Those are conflicting labels.  While explaining complex relations with labels is oversimplification, it's a starting point.  Being conservative means to oppose change, and particularly changing yourself.  Trying to keep the environment from changing, if necessary by changing yourself, is not conservative but conservationist.

Comment: That's not the definition of conservatism. They don't blindly oppose any and all change. Conservatism means to support changes with small and careful steps, while liberalism means changes with drastic steps. Evolution vs revolution.

Comment: Climate change is a form of radical change, so by this reasoning, conservatives should radically oppose any industrial activity because it means change.  I haven't seen conservatives radically oppose drilling in nature reserves or building pipelines, both of which mean change.

Comment: @vsz: Liberalism doesn't mean changes with either drastic steps or otherwise. Liberalism doesn't have any particular opinion on changes in general.

Comment: @Gábor : I meant the viewpoints on change itself, from conservative or liberal view. Of course both conservatism and liberalism contain many stances in many topics, not just about the topic of changes.

Comment: or conservative means pro-preservation.  which should mean that the label implies rigorous environmentalism.  you can spin labels any way you want.